# autocomplete - show "no results"

Tags: jquery

The following code checks if a value under div class="ids" exists, and if it does, it will show me the result when I search for it. For example: value = Headphones -- will autocomplete and show "Headphones". What I am trying to do is to add a check that autocompletes a text that says "no results" when the value you're searching for wasn't found.

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = $.makeArray($('div.ids').map((i,d)=>$(d).text()));
$("#Search").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
});
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Protip: You're working with *elements*, not tags. Tags just represent elements in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = $.makeArray($('div.ids').map((i,d)=>$(d).text()));
    if(availableTags.length < 1){availableTags.push("No Results")}

    $("#Search").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
});
```

Comment: It works to me... add to codepen your code to help you!

Comment: can you make a gif or take a screenshot to show what you get